# Passing base64 into json request C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, rest

I'm having a problem with passing base64 into my json call

I'm defining baseImage as a string in my code, However, whenever I'm running my service on SOAP UI, it doesn't even run due to base64 parameter being in my call.

Below is what i get
[image]

This is my class

```
 public class InsertPostwithImageRequest
    {
        //public string UserName { get; set; }
        //public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string EncodedImage {get; set;}
      //  public string PostedAs { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update: I tried passing a 3 letter strings, it's working fine, however, when I'm passing the stringfied base64, it does not respond**

Comment: I would recommend to try this: 
Use the JavaScript function ‘JSON.stringify(encodedData)’ which returns an escaped string that you can use it with no problems in your JSON afterwards.

Comment: If it doesn't run does that mean you are getting an exception?

Comment: it doesn't even run, it just gives the same response as attached above, i wonder if its related to defining it as a string, i tried stringifying it but still no response from the service, however, if i removed the base64 parameter from the call, it works fine.why?

Comment: I'm not getting an exception that's the problem

Comment: How big/long is the Base64 string?